# NSUserDefaults strange behaviour - changing stored values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I'm building an app for tap counting (for example: people going into the room). The main goal is to be able to have multiple counters (for example: counter for main room, counter for white room, counter for green room etc.).

The app consists of:

1) A list of counters - `CounterListTableViewController`, with function is to create new items (counters) in the list

2) A counter page - `RowCounterViewController`

Issue #1: In the `RowCounterViewController` counted value is stored to `NSUserDefaults`. After tapping let's say 3 times in the counter, returning to the list through navigator bar button "back" and then back to that counter shows 3 in the UILabel. So far, all is good, but if i return to the list more than 1 time the value starts changing. What is happening?

This is the NSLog of the situation explained above:

```
2015-01-02 23:51:56.243 RowCounter[8522:380477] {
    0 = 0;
    1 = 0;
    2 = 0;
}
// here I tap 3 times in the counter with index "0" in the list

2015-01-02 23:52:07.184 RowCounter[8522:380477] {
    0 = 3;
    1 = 0;
    2 = 0;
}
// I return to the list and go back to the same counter, 3 times is there

2015-01-02 23:52:11.594 RowCounter[8522:380477] {
    0 = 0;
    1 = 0;
    2 = 0;
}
// I return again to the list and again back to the same counter, it now shows 0 (but should be 3)

2015-01-02 23:52:17.902 RowCounter[8522:380477] {
    0 = 0;
    1 = 0;
    2 = 0;
}
// I now go to the counter with index "1" and tap 5 times

2015-01-02 23:52:27.591 RowCounter[8522:380477] {
    0 = 0;
    1 = 5;
    2 = 0;
}
// I return to the list and go to a different counter with index "2", in the counter with index "1" count is 5

2015-01-02 23:52:30.401 RowCounter[8522:380477] {
    0 = 0;
    1 = 5;
    2 = 0;
}
// I again return to the list and again go to a different counter with index "2", in the counter with index "1" count is still 5

2015-01-02 23:52:34.029 RowCounter[8522:380477] {
    0 = 0;
    1 = 5;
    2 = 0;
}
// I again return to the list and again go to a different counter with index "2", in the counter with index "1" count is still 5 - So if not returning to the counter with count >0 it holds that count

2015-01-02 23:52:37.144 RowCounter[8522:380477] {
    0 = 0;
    1 = 0;
    2 = 0;
}
// I return to the list and go to the counter with index "1" and count 5 clears.
```

Issue #2: This is probably connected to the first issue, I am loosing the count when Home button is pressed, but since I am loosing the count anyway, this could be resolved if the first issue is resolved.

Code where I store and load the view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveCount) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveCount) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"saveCount"] ;
    NSLog(@"%@", dict);

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)_itemIndex] ;
    NSInteger numCounter = [[dict objectForKey:key] intValue] ;
    if (numCounter) {
        // counter = [numCounter intValue] ;
        count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)numCounter] ;
    } else {
        numCounter = 0 ;
        count.text = @"0" ;
    }
}


- (void)saveCount {
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"saveCount"] ;
    NSMutableDictionary *mDict = nil ;
    if (dict == nil)
        mDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary] ;
    else
        mDict = [dict mutableCopy] ;

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)_itemIndex] ;
    [mDict setObject:@(counter) forKey:key] ;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mDict forKey:@"saveCount"] ;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] ;
}
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Why did you comment out line `counter = [numCounter intValue];`? I see that you save `counter` to user defaults, but you don't initialize it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I have declared `int counter` in the .h file, line `counter = [numCounter intValue]` is giving me an error `bad receiver type 'NSInteger' (aka "long")`, this could make this issue as i choose to ignore counter, not sure how to set it without this error @OleksiiTaran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the problem:

my commented line `counter = [numCounter intValue]` 
gave an error `bad receiver type 'NSInteger' (aka "long")`

Initially i have declared `int counter`
Changed it to `NSInteger counter`

uncommented the line above and changed to:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)_itemIndex] ;
NSInteger numCounter = [[dict objectForKey:key] intValue] ;
if (numCounter > 0) {
    counter = numCounter;
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)numCounter] ;
} else {
    numCounter = 0 ;
    count.text = @"0" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be incorrect:

```
NSInteger numCounter = [[dict objectForKey:key] intValue] ;
if (numCounter) {
```

You are checking here if `numCounter` equals one

I guess it should be

```
NSInteger numCounter = [[dict objectForKey:key] intValue] ;
if (numCounter > 0) {
```

But then again you can rewrite the whole thing to

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)_itemIndex];
NSNumber* numCounter = dict[key];
if(!numCounter) 
    numCounter = @0;

count.text = [numCounter stringValue];
```

Comment: The changes do not resolve the issue explained. Good to see you again Sebastian;)

Comment: Note that `if (numCounter)` doesn't test whether the value of `numCounter` is one, but rather whether it is non-zero.

Comment: Thank you! Damn, the whole answer became irrelevant :)